# Error occur installing MySQL-Python

Tags: python, mysql

An error occurs while installing MySQL - python to 'python version v2.7 required, which was not found in regstry'. What should I do? Note that I used python v2.7.3, win7 64bit

Comment: Have you checked env variables?

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the executable from the link below for windows 7, I had the same problem when installing from the source and then I tried the executables and it worked.
Link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Search for mysql-python, there are list of executables.